# Change div width live with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, width

Is it possible to change a `div`'s width live with jQuery? And if it is, how?

What I want is to change its width depending on the browser's window width in real time, so if/when the user changes the browser window, the `div`'s dimensions are changed as well in realtime.

Comment: Are you sure that you need JavaScript for this?

Comment: Why not using liquid layout using CSS ?

Comment: Yes it is. Have you attempted anything yourself? Even a quick Google will turn up some good documentation at the least.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use, which will be triggered when the window resizes.

```
$( window ).bind("resize", function(){
    // Change the width of the div
    $("#yourdiv").width( 600 );
});
```

If you want a DIV width as percentage of the screen, just use CSS `width : 80%;`.

Answer (score 19):

It is indeed possible to change a `div` elements' width in jQuery:

```
$("#div").css("width", "300px");
```

However, what you're describing can be better and more effectively achieved in CSS by setting a width as a percentage:

```
#div {
    width: 75%;
    /* You can also specify min/max widths */
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

This div will then always be 75% the width of the screen, unless the screen width means the div will be smaller than 300px, or bigger than 960px.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do this:

**CSS:** Use width as %, like 75%, so the width of the div will change automatically when user resizes the browser.

**Javascipt:** Use *resize* event

```
$(window).bind('resize', function()
{
    if($(window).width() > 500)
        $('#divID').css('width', '300px');
    else
        $('divID').css('width', '200px');
});
```

Hope this will help you **:)**

Comment: `.css()` support width in percentage but `.width()` doesn't. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use a percentage width for the `div`? Setting the width to 50% will make it 50% as wide as the window (assuming there is no parent element with a width assigned to it).

Answer (score 0):

Got better solution:

```
$('#element').resizable({
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#element').height(ui.originalSize.height);
    }
});
```

Comment: The question is about adjusting width, not height