# Expanding div width

Tags: jquery, animation, responsive-design

Hey guys I have a little problem.

I have a div with an id of '`#content`' and another with an id of `'#chat'`. I used jQuery to make the chat div slide up and down on command by clicking a link, but now I wanna make the content div increase it's width to 90% when the chat div is down. here's the css:

```
    #chat {
        width:20%;
        height:84.5%;
        background-color:#000;
        border:1px solid #FFF;
        float:right;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        margin-top:0;
        position:fixed;
        z-index:3;
    }



     #content {
            width:70%;
            height:600px;
            background-color:#FFF;
            bottom:0;
            margin-top:20px;
            float:left;
            margin-left:5%;
        }
```

and here's the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chat').hide();
    $('.chatToggle').click(function(){
        $('#chat').toggle('slide');
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153281/change-div-width-live-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$( "#chat" ).toggle( "slide", function() {
  if(!$("#chat").is(":visible")) {
    $("#content").css("width","90%");
  } else {
    $("#content").css("width","70%");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class for the chat panel to determine if it's opened.

```
$('.chatToggle').click(function () {
    if ($('#chat').hasClass("opened")) {
        $('#chat').removeClass("opened");
        $('#content').css("width", "90%");
    }
    else {
        $('#chat').addClass("opened");
        $('#content').css("width", "70%");
    }
    $('#chat').toggle('slide');
});
```