# HTML: persist style changes (e.g., width, position) made with jQuery as cleanly as SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

The goal is to persist dynamic style changes (e.g., width, background color, rotation, position) made with jQuery.

With SVG, this is easy. Assume some rectangle is 50% of its parent's width. If you want it to be 75% instead, change the `width` attribute. Then you can save the document, and this change persists without extra work.

**50% Width:**

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <rect width="50%" height="50%" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

**75% Width:**

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <rect width="75%" height="75%" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

With HTML and jQuery, it's different. If you change the rectangle's width with jQuery [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153281/change-div-width-live-with-jquery), the change doesn't appear in the document.

How can you persist this and other style changes on the server?

It seems like there are two options, neither of which feel as clean as SVG. Is there an alternative?

**Option 1:** Don't use jQuery to change the rectangle. Update the `style` attribute manually, so the style changes appear inlined.

**Option 2:** Use jQuery to change the rectangle, but persist changes with custom attributes like "data-width." When loading the document, initialize elements based on these custom attributes. Effectively, this option requires you to duplicate functionality you get free with SVG.

Comment: When you use `$.width` to change the width of a dom element, that width is inlined like so `<div style="width: 50px;"/>`...otherwise it's not really clear what you're asking

Comment: @Ted thanks for the clarification. Using jQuery outerWidth doesn't inline the changes as indicated in the link. Please post as an answer that changing the property directly with jQuery will inline the change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the property directly with jQuery will inline the change. When you use [$.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2) to change the width of a dom element, that width is inlined like so `<div style="width: 50px;"/>`